# How to join duplicate arrays by value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, join, duplicates

I have array for example:

```
$myArr1 = array(
"word1" => "hello",
"word2" => "hi",
"word3" => "welcome",
);

$myArr2 = array(
"word1" => "hello",
"word3" => "welcome",
"word2" => "hola"
);
```

How to make join duplicate keys "word" and if there are duplicates join it values to get output:

```
"word1" => "hello",
"word2" => "hi hola",
"word3" => "welcome"
```

Comment: can you tell us  more clearly what you exactly want?

Comment: You cant possibly have two keys

Comment: the scenario you have mentioned can not be occurred since a single dimensional associative array can not have two 'same keys'.

Comment: Right, i can not have 2 same keys. I change it to 2 arrays then. How to make it done best way in this example?

Answer (score 2):

```
 $result = array();
 foreach($myArr1 as $k=>$v) {

    if($myArr1[$k]  == $myArr2[$k])
    {
        $result[] = $v;
    }
    else
    {
        $result[] = $v.' '.$myArr2[$k];
    }

}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the result

```
$myArr1 = array(
"word1" => "hello",
"word2" => "hi",
"word3" => "welcome",
);

$myArr2 = array(
"word1" => "hello",
"word3" => "welcome",
"word2" => "hola"
);

$myArr3 = merge_duplicate_values($myArr1,$myArr2);

function merge_duplicate_values($myArr1,$myArr2){

$myArr3=array_merge_recursive($myArr1,$myArr2);

 foreach($myArr3 as $key => $val){

    if(is_array($val)){
         $myArr3[$key] = implode(' ',array_unique($val));

       }
 }

 return $myArr3; // its your desired result
}
```

Comment: This code will print hi hi and welcome welcome also.!

Comment: Please check it again dear  $myArr3[$key] = implode(' ',array_unique($val));

Answer (score 0):

How about making a function?

```
function pushWordToArray($arr,$word,$key)...
```

in the function you would then check if the $key already exists and then concat the existing word and the $word you're inputting.

EDIT:

Answer to the edited question.

Just run through the both arrays and concat the two duplicate keys (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Loop the values against the other one, append if needed. You can do something like:

```
$myArr1 = array(
"word1" => "hello",
"word2" => "hi",
"word3" => "welcome",
);


$myArr2 = array(
"word1" => "hello",
"word3" => "welcome",
"word2" => "hola"
);


foreach($myArr2 as $key => &$value) {
    if($myArr1[$key] != $myArr2[$key]) {
        $myArr1[$key] .= ' '.$value;
    }
}

print_r($myArr1);
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [word1] => hello
    [word2] => hi hola
    [word3] => welcome
)
```

Comment: @SumanBiswas why youre feelings are hurt (cry hoohoo). changed my answer. happy now?

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArr3 = array_merge_recursive($myArr1, $myArr2);

foreach($myArr3 as $key => $value){

    if(!is_array($myArr3[$key])){
            continue;
    }

    if($value[0] === $value[1]){
            $myArr3[$key] = $value[0];
    }else{
            $myArr3[$key] = implode(' ', $value);
    }
}

// print_r($myArr3);
```